# One-click VPN "system program problem detected "

Tags: uninstall, vpn, system

friends,

i am very new to ubuntu, i tried to get VPN one click , but after installed it, it gets me every time at start up and when i try to open it this message "system  program problem detected "[https://i.stack.imgur.com/cB4Y9.png]
How to remove it and rid of this message

Comment: Not sure if it really comes from VPN.  Could you update / upgrade you system?

Comment: i make report for the problem and check the details , i found oneclick vpn and the message comes up when i open it, yea i have just update my system